# Working with relations in ORM

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

What is the best/common solution (best practices) to working with relationships in ORM (from long-life project view)?

1) E.g. I have Oracle HR schema. Is it ok to create relations between every objects (entities) where it is possible or only between objects where I really need now (and change in future)?

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private long employeeId;
    @ManyToOne((fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Job job;
}

@Entity
public class Job {
    @Id
    private String jobId;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Employee> employeeList;
}
```

2) How should I store/set new Employee with existing or new Job? We have Employee entity with String jobId and also created relation Job job variable:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private long employeeId;
    private String jobId;
    @ManyToOne((fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Job job;
}
```

The worst solutions is set both parameters everytime:

```
Job job = new Job();
job.setJobId("JOB_01");
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.setEmployeeId(1L)
employee.setJobId(job.getJobId());
```

A little bit better solutions is re-implement setJobId() method in Employee class (there should be also some code to find out if mentioned Job exist or not):

```
public void setJobId(String jobId) {
    if (getJob() == null) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
        job = new Job();
        job.setJobId(jobId);
    } else {
        this.jobId = getJob().getJobId();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need an association, then you don't need to add it. Note however that even if it's not used in Java code directly, an association might still be useful just to be able to traverse it in JPQL or criteria queries.

Regarding your jobId field, it should just be removed from the `Employee` entity. An employee has a job, and you can access its job ID using `employee.getJob().getId()`. You shouldn't be able to set the job ID of an employee. Instead, you should get or create a job (in the service layer), and set the employee's job using `setJob(job)`.

Comment: And is there some nice solutions how store new Employee with existing Job? Because when I call job.setJobId("AC_ACCOUNT") and employee.setJob(job) then system tries to touch (store new job or update existing one) Job table.

Comment: Get the job with the given ID from database (with em.find or em.getReference or session.get or session.load), and set this job in the employee.

Comment: Problem is not getting existing Job but for creating new Employee I call em.persist(employee) and it looks that system calls also persist on Job. ORA-00001: unique constraint (HR.JOB_ID_PK) violated

Comment: You should never create a new Job instance and set its ID yourself to refer to an already existing Job. You should get it from the database. Else, Hibernate thinks the job you're setting in the employee is a new job that must be created along with the employee.

Comment: even if I fill-in all parameters the same like in DB?.. I know it is wrong solutions. But your proposal  does not work:  Job job = jobDao.findJob("AC_ACCOUNT"); Employee employee = new Employee(); <set employee params>; employee.setJob(job); em.persist(employee) ...throws mentioned exception.

Comment: Then you have a problem with your mapping. Ask another question where you show your entities and their mapping annotations, and the code used to persist your employee.

Comment: oops you are right I had @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) in my Employee class on Job param. A removed cascade and it works. Thank you a lot.

Comment: It should work even with the cascade. You have another problem with your mapping.

Comment: Yep, it works but I had "simple" type String jobId and also object Job in my Employee class, so I removed "simple" type.